# SQL Server to Event hub - event duplication

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, azure-eventhub

My application consumes events from an event hub. The event hub is populated by an Azure SQL Server database. Then, a single consumer consumes the events from the hub.

As I understand, events on the event hub may be duplicated (since event hub uses "at least once" policy). For example, a SQL query, that was performed once on the DB, may reside more than once in the event hub (due to some communication failures + retries)

My questions are:

1. Am I correct (a single SQL Server event may reside on an event hub more than once)? If so, can these duplicated SQL Server events reside on different partitions?
2. How can I recognize duplicated events (as there is no "Message ID" field in each SQL Server event)?

Thank you very much,

Eitan.

Answer (score 0):

1.Your duplicated events may reside on the same or different partitions due to the load balancing factors

2.To detect the duplicated events you can use the combination of sequence number and [partitionkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide#partition-key) as comparison factor as the sequence number of the events are unique within a partition.

Answer (score 0):

How your data is being copied to the Event Hub will determine the strategy you need to use here...see below.

1. It depends on how the data was sent to Event Hub on whether the duplicated records will be in different partitions. If the code sending the data to Event Hub set a [PartitionKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.partitionkey?view=azure-dotnet), and that [PartitionKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.partitionkey?view=azure-dotnet) was the same each time the record was sent, then the duplicated records will reside in the same partition.
2. In order to determine duplicates, you need some unique ID (or combination of fields to create a unique ID) that will always be the same for the same record. The unique ID would normally be used as the PartitionKey if ordering is important.